# How to apply Strong Markov Property Using Definition

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am currently learning Markov Chain, and I have just learned the definition of strong Markov Property. However, I am confused about applying the strong property in an exercise about "number of visits". The solution suggests that I can apply strong Markov property in the highlighted part However, I do not know how to justify using the definition of strong Markov property.[Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2kk6.png)---[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV674.png)---[Definition of SMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sU9B.png)

Here is my own attempt:

$P_i(V_i\geq2|V_i\geq1)=P_i(V_i\geq2|T_i\leq\infty)$

$=P_i(\exists k\geq1, X_{T_i+k}=i|X_{T_i}=i; X_\alpha\neq i, \alpha\in[1,T_i))$

$=P_i(\exists k\geq1, X_{T_i+k}=i|X_{T_i}=i)$   ----- Apply SMP

$=P_i(\exists k\geq1, X_{k}=i|X_0=i)$           ----- I want to use homogeneity

$=P_i(V_i\geq1)$

In addition, I have more or less prove the first highlighted part using standard Markov Property [(justification)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoYiN.png). However, I am not sure how to justify my homogeneity step because the following relation $P_i(X_{n+k}=j)=p_{ij}$ is the result of Chapman-Kolmogorov equation. In my case, the event has a "there exists" statement, does homogeneity still hold?

Any comment is welcome, and please leave comments if you are confused with my description.